# How much weight can this DC motor and wheel combination carry?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, torque

I'm trying to make a RC Car with a total weight around 1kg. It will be 4-wheel drive with differential drive algorithm. The count of motors will be 4 DC motors simply. I have chosen the following motor.

The wheel diameter is 4cm for now. I'm trying to achieve a speed of 0.20881 m/s roughly. I want the car to achieve that speed in min. 20 seconds.

[Motor Link](https://robu.in/product/n20-6v-100-rpm-micro-metal-gear-box-dc-motor/?gclid=CjwKCAjw8KmLBhB8EiwAQbqNoKURTUFUTi-pB22IKxKDiFXiT-9woFUH1OkL3G25E2z7OWUkSQ2YmhoC62YQAvD_BwE)

Following are its parameters as described in the link:

RPM - 100

Torque - 2kg-cm

Supply Voltage- 3.7-6V

Weight - 20g

How can i estimate with these things how much weight my RC Car can carry?

Comment: The motor doesn't "carry" the load; the wheels and suspension do. The motor will **accelerate** the load against friction, air resistance, inertia and gravity if not running on the flat. So you need to write some specifications for what your requirements are and then start calculating. Note that you have chosen a vendor that does not supply datasheets for the motor so you have little guarantee of any specification.

Comment: DC motors don't carry weight; they drive the wheels so work out what maximum speed you need to achieve and how fast you want to accelerate to that speed fully-laden and calculate the power exerted in doing that. Then, it boils down to your motors being able to deliver that power.

Comment: If the motor shaft is direct to the wheel, then the motor is indeed carrying the weight in its bearings. This being a gearmotor, that’s happening in the gearbox, but the same constraint applies.

Comment: Ok I do understand it is the wheels that would be responsible for the weight to carry. I have added the average speed and the time i want it to reach it possibly trying. Now how do i understand if the wheels can take 1kg of load.

Comment: When i mean that wheels and motor can take the following load. I mean will I be able to achieve that speed with these motors?

Comment: "roughly" 0.20881 m/s?? That sounds like an excessively precise number to me, not a rough estimate! In any case, you can certainly reach that speed in well under a second, if you drop it from a height--the speed you can go will depend on the terrain.

Answer (score 1):

Your velocity calculations are correct for 100 RPM.

The motor is rated at 0.7 kg.cm. A torque of 0.7 kg.cm on a wheel with radius of 2 cm will give 0.35 kg force between the rim and the ground. 0.35 kg of force = 3.5 N. (0.35 × 9.81 N to be precise.)

From \$ F = ma \$ we can calculate \$ a = \frac F m = \frac {3.5} 1 = 3.5 \ \mathrm{m^2/s} \$.

All this ignores friction, etc.